# How do you "sleep" in an AnyEvent callback without pausing the whole script?

Tags: perl, asynchronous, sleep, anyevent

I'm specificaly using AnyEvent::Inotify::Simple (using EV as backend) to monitor file events.  So I have a handler callback that in a particular case, I need to "pause" before continuing.  `sleep` obviously halts everything (so other events don't get handled until after `sleep` is done), so I tried using `alarm` however if the same scenario occurs  that sets the alarm again, the original alarm (and therefore its `$SIG{ALRM}` sub) is ignored and only the "new" one is run.

```
#sleep-based approach (definitely a no-go)
sub handler {
    my ( $self, $event, $file ) = @_;
    #do some stuff
    ...
    if( $some_condition_exists ) {
        sleep(3);
        #now that we've waited, if some change occurred then do stuff
        if ( $new_change_occurred ) {
            #do some new stuff
        }
    }
    return;
}

#alarm -based approach (still a no-go when callback is called again while original alarm is still counting down)
sub handler {
    my ( $self, $event, $file ) = @_;
    #do some stuff
    ...
    if( $some_condition_exists ) {
        $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
             #now that we've waited, if some change occurred then do stuff
             if ( $new_change_occurred ) {
                 #do some new stuff
             }
        }
        alarm(3);
    }
    return;
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated?  All I need is a way to make the callback pause while continuing to handle new inotify events asynchronously.

Comment: Use `$cv->recv` to sleep, and do `$cv->send` when a change occurs.

Comment: You use use `AE::timer(3, $cv);` to provide a timeout.

Comment: AnyEvent->timer() was probably the correct approach and I had already tried it but never got it to work from within the AnyEvent::Inotify::Simple event_receiver callback.  I'm not sure if it somehow conflicted with running EV loop (tied to inotify) or just the wrong usage.  At any rate, my solution, was using POE::Session delay_add.  It seems a bit crazy to introduce another event framewok(especially one so bulky) to the same app but it did work.  I considered using POEx::Inotify instead of AnyEvent::Inotify::Simple but it wouldn've meant a significant rewrite of my app.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you're in `recv`, the event queue will be checked for the timer event, so it can be used to make a timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an AnyEvent::timer, make sure you keep track of the guard object it returns.  I typically store them in a global.

If you assign it to a variable that goes out of scope, the timer will be canceled.

```
my $guards;

sub handler {
    my ( $self, $event, $file ) = @_;
    #do some stuff
    ...
    if( $some_condition_exists ) {
        $guards->{$file} = AE::timer 3,0,sub {
             #now that we've waited, if some change occurred then do stuff
             if ( $new_change_occurred ) {
                 #do some new stuff
             }
        };
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what was happening.  The timer fell out of scope when the handler callback returned and died a quiet death.  A "duh" moment but thanks for pointing it out!